# Detecting rectangles using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv3.0

So i'm completely new to OpenCV and for the past 2-3 days i've searched a lot about how to use OpenCV in Java and Android studio to perform perspective correction and detect biggest rectangle in bitmaps and based on my searches i have done some work but the result bitmap is not correct.I'm sure i've done a lot of things wrong so it would be great if someone help me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{

    Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    Mat matImage = new Mat(myImage.getHeight(),myImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Bitmap myBitmap32 = myImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, matImage);

    correctPerspective(matImage);
}
```

---

```
public static void correctPerspective(Mat imgSource)
{

    // convert the image to black and white does (8 bit)
    Imgproc.Canny(imgSource.clone(), imgSource, 50, 50);

    // apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new org.opencv.core.Size(5, 5), 5);

    // find the contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    double maxArea = -1;
    MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); 
    // index 0 for starting
    // point
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
        temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
        double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
        // compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
        if (contourarea > maxArea) {
            // check if this contour is a square
            MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f(temp_contour.toArray());
            int contourSize = (int) temp_contour.total();
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve_temp = new MatOfPoint2f();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve_temp, contourSize * 0.05, true);
            if (approxCurve_temp.total() == 4) {
                maxArea = contourarea;
                approxCurve = approxCurve_temp;
            }
        }
    }

    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);

    double[] temp_double;
    temp_double = approxCurve.get(0, 0);
    Point p1 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    temp_double = approxCurve.get(1, 0);
    Point p2 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    temp_double = approxCurve.get(2, 0);
    Point p3 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    temp_double = approxCurve.get(3, 0);
    Point p4 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    List<Point> source = new ArrayList<Point>();
    source.add(p1);
    source.add(p2);
    source.add(p3);
    source.add(p4);
    Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(source);

    Mat result = warp(imgSource, startM);

    //Saving into bitmap
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.cols(),  result.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
    Mat tmp = new Mat (result.cols(), result.rows(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
    Imgproc.cvtColor(result, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, resultBitmap);

}
```

---

```
public static Mat warp(Mat inputMat, Mat startM)
{

    int resultWidth = 1200;
    int resultHeight = 680;

    Point ocvPOut4 = new Point(0, 0);
    Point ocvPOut1 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
    Point ocvPOut2 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
    Point ocvPOut3 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);

    if (inputMat.height() > inputMat.width())
    {
        ocvPOut3 = new Point(0, 0);
        ocvPOut4 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
        ocvPOut1 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
        ocvPOut2 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);
    }

    Mat outputMat = new Mat(resultWidth, resultHeight, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    List<Point> dest = new ArrayList<Point>();
    dest.add(ocvPOut1);
    dest.add(ocvPOut2);
    dest.add(ocvPOut3);
    dest.add(ocvPOut4);

    Mat endM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dest);

    Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM, endM);

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputMat, outputMat, perspectiveTransform, new Size(resultWidth, resultHeight), Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);

    return outputMat;
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution